# select all datagridview rows to another gridview

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to copy all rows from the first datagridview into a second but I don't want the empty row from the first datagridview and i need to reformat the layout for the 2nd datagridview. this is driving me nuts - need help.

```
    private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    dgvData.SelectAll();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc;
        DataRow dr;

        //build cols
        dc = new DataColumn();
        dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        dc.ColumnName = "DS";
        dc.Unique = false;
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        dc = new DataColumn();
        dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        dc.ColumnName = "GLAccount";
        dc.Unique = false;
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        dc = new DataColumn();
        dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        dc.ColumnName = "SubAccount";
        dc.Unique = false;
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        dc = new DataColumn();
        //dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
        dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        dc.ColumnName = "Date";
        dc.Unique = false;
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        dc = new DataColumn();
        dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        dc.ColumnName = "Description";
        dc.Unique = false;
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        dc = new DataColumn();
        dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
        dc.ColumnName = "Amount";
        dc.Unique = false;
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        //build rows
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvData.SelectedRows)
        {
            //how do i prevent copying over the empty row which happens to be the last row in the first datagridview?

        int i;
        i = dgvData.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex; //should this start with the first row?
        int month = 12;
        DateTime y = DateTime.Now;
        int year = y.Year;

        for (int ir = 1; ir <= month; ir++)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["DS"] = dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            dr["GLAccount"] = dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            dr["SubAccount"] = dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

            if (ir == 7)
            {
                dr["Date"] = "1/01/" + (year + 1).ToString();
            }
            else if (ir == 8)
            {
                dr["Date"] = "2/01/" + (year + 1).ToString();
            }
            else if (ir == 9)
            {
                dr["Date"] = "3/01/" + (year + 1).ToString();
            }
            else if (ir == 10)
            {
                dr["Date"] = "4/01/" + (year + 1).ToString();
            }
            else if (ir == 11)
            {
                dr["Date"] = "5/01/" + (year + 1).ToString();
            }
            else if (ir == 12)
            {
                dr["Date"] = "6/01/" + (year + 1).ToString();
            }
            else if (ir == 1)
            {
                dr["Date"] = "7/01/" + year.ToString();
            }
            else if (ir == 2)
            {
                dr["Date"] = "8/01/" + year.ToString();
            }
            else if (ir == 3)
            {
                dr["Date"] = "9/01/" + year.ToString();
            }
            else if (ir == 4)
            {
                dr["Date"] = "10/01/" + year.ToString();
            }
            else if (ir == 5)
            {
                dr["Date"] = "11/01/" + year.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                dr["Date"] = "12/01/" + year.ToString();
            }

            dr["Description"] = dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            if (ir == 7)
            {
                if (dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value == null || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value == "" || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value);
                }
            }
            else if (ir == 8)
            {
                if (dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value == null || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value == "" || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value);
                }
            }
            else if (ir == 9)
            {
                if (dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value == null || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value == "" || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value);
                }
            }
            else if (ir == 10)
            {
                if (dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value == null || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value == "" || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value);
                }
            }
            else if (ir == 11)
            {
                if (dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[14].Value == null || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[14].Value == "" || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[14].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[14].Value);
                }
            }
            else if (ir == 12)
            {
                if (dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[15].Value == null || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[15].Value == "" || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[15].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[15].Value);
                }
            }
            else if (ir == 1)
            {
                if (dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value == null || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value == "" || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                }
            }
            else if (ir == 2)
            {
                if (dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value == null || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value == "" || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                }
            }
            else if (ir == 3)
            {
                if (dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value == null || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value == "" || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
                }
            }
            else if (ir == 4)
            {
                if (dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value == null || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value == "" || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
                }
            }
            else if (ir == 5)
            {
                if (dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value == null || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value == "" || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value == null || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value == "" || dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value);
                }
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
      }

        //bind
        dgvConverted.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Comment: How does Excel relate to this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `row.IsNewRow` at the beginning of your `foreach` loop to check to see if the row being copied is the blank row.

**Added Code Example**

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvData.SelectedRows)
  {
   if (!row.IsNewRow)
     {
        //Your other code here
     }
   }
```

I'm not sure why you are using the `i` iterator since you can simply use `row.Cells[]` instead of `dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[]`

Comment: excel - i first import the data from excel into the first datagridvew then am trying to copy that data into the next datagridview. i figured out how to remove the empty row in the first datagridview -- DataBindingComplete - deleted last row.

Comment: so i tried the row.IsNewRow and now nothing is copied over to the 2nd datagridview.

Comment: //build rows
            dgvData.SelectAll();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvData.SelectedRows)
            {

            int i;
            i = dgvData.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            int month = 12;
            DateTime y = DateTime.Now;
            int year = y.Year;

            for (int ir = 1; ir <= month; ir++)
            {
                if (row.IsNewRow)
                {
                    dr = dt.NewRow();

Comment: @kx250f , See my amended answer.  Basically, you don't execute the rest of the `foreach` code if the Row is new.

Comment: regardless of what i do i get the following -- there are two rows in the 1st datagridview dgvData. when i click the convert button it takes the last row from the dgvData and puts it into the 2nd datagridview 24 times as opposed to having 12 rows per date. the first row is totally ignored. i don't get this at all - why it doesn't work?

Comment: @kx250f, Example: Replace `dr["DS"] = dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();` with `dr["DS"] = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();`.  You can get rid if the `i` then.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using a `foreach` loop then getting the row index wrong.

Just use a `for` loop and have a proper index.

Comment: how is that? change this line to a for loop?

Comment: foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvData.SelectedRows) -- I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: if i do the following i always get the last row from the 1st dgv.

Comment: //foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvData.SelectedRows)
            for (int i = 1; i < this.dgvData.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //int i;
                //i = dgvData.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;  //commented out or not always get last row only
                int month = 12;
                DateTime y = DateTime.Now;
                int year = y.Year;

                    for (int ir = 1; ir <= month; ir++)
                    {
                        dr = dt.NewRow();

Comment: this might have worked:  for (int i = 0; i < this.dgvData.Rows.Count; i++)   i changed the i = 1 to 0.

Comment: Grrr sorry, typo. start the `for` loop at 0 like so `for (int i = 0; i < this.dgvData.Rows.Count; i++)`